# Objective-C for Dummies: How to make App Delegate communicate with Controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

how can I invoke methods in my controllers from within the app delegate. For example, my application uses the app delegate to monitor the user's location. After the location has been determined I want to call a method on a controller which has a MKMapView on it and show the user's location on it. How can I go about doing that?

Here's my current code:

```
//  AppDelegate.m
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [[[DashboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DashboardViewController" bundle:nil] displayMyLocation:newLocation.coordinate];
}
```

Also tried this, which is crashing with `SIGABRT`, but is at least attempting to call the method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [(DashboardViewController *)dashboardViewController displayMyLocation:manager];
}
```

Alternatively, now that I think about it, would it be wrong to have the controller also monitor the user's location and just self invoke it's methods? If I remember correctly having multiple CLLocationManagerDelegate delegates didn't affect performance because they all access the GPS identically? Is that right or wrong? It just kinda seems dumb to have multiple instances of the same thing...

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE for @nevan**

The map code:

```
- (void)displayMyLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;

    region.center = location.coordinate;
    region.span = span;

    [map setRegion:region];
}
```

Comment: You may want to create an instance of the view controller as part of the app delegate to have permanent access to it. Using two CLLocationManager instances isn't a bad option either. It avoids creating a new dependency between the app delegate and the view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation` is called many times, each time the device gets a new fix on the location, so you'll end up allocing and initing your DashboardViewController many times. The proper way to do this would be to alloc and init a dashboardViewController instance variable when you set up your app delegate, then use that instance variable. It looks like you've done that in your second piece of code, but I don't understand why you have to cast it to be a DashboardViewController.

It would be better again to put the location manager into the same place as your mapview. Why not move `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation` to there?

Comment: After your question about the casting, I realized that I can just set the variable to the actual controller class, so I learned something there, thanks! I ended up moving the `locationManager` to the controller as you suggested (again), and it seems to be working, up to the point that it's not marking the map, but that's another issue...

Comment: Yup, it's set in the map view. I've updated my question above with the code I'm using to display the region. It works fine on an iPad prototype app I've got, so I'm not too sure why it would fail here...

Comment: Is the problem that you can't see the blue dot, or that the map view won't move to the new location? The code you posted looks fine to me.

Comment: Lol, I figured it out. I never linked the variable from the controller to the IBOutlet in the XIB. There's so much to do within these apps that if you forget one simple little thing, you end up smashing your head through walls trying to find 'major' bugs... Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It would certainly be a good idea to have your controller monitoring for location events.

A fairly decent alternative would be to use the notification center to notify the controller that a new location is available. I actually did exactly that in one of my applications. [Check out line 70 of this file to see how to send a notification](https://github.com/nippysaurus/WeatherRock/blob/master/Location.m) and [line 54 of this file to see how tp subscribe tp these notifications](https://github.com/nippysaurus/WeatherRock/blob/master/BrissyBomAppDelegate.m).

Comment: I tried the notifications way, and it probably does work except it was crashing for me when I was trying to grab the `newLocation` variable for some reason, so I ended up going with a controller based monitor. Thanks for the tip on the notification though, it will probably come in handy at some point.